# swift 3 using speech recognition and AVFoundation together

Tags: ios, swift3, speech-recognition, avaudioplayer

I am successfully able to use Speech (speech recognition) and I can use AVFoundation to play wav files in Xcode 8/IOS 10. I just can't use them both together.  I have working speech recognition code where I import Speech.  When I import AVFoundation into the same app and use the following code, there is no sound and no errors are generated:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
func playAudio()  {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file.wav", ofType: nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer = sound
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        //handle error
    }

}
```

I assume it is because both use audio.  Can anyone suggest how to use both in the same app? I also find that I cannot use speech recognition and text-to-speech together in the same app.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 7):

You should change this line:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

on to:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
```

This should work ;-)

Comment: I prefer your fix for its simplicity, but when I implement it, the playback volume changes to very low after the first speech recognition.

Answer (score 6):

I just bumped into the same problem, and here is how I solved,

add the following line when Speech Recognition is done. What it does is basically setting the audio session back to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback category.

```
   let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try audioSession.setActive(false, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        // handle errors
    }
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `AVAudioPlayer` stops playing the sample if you're using `AVAudioSession` to record the microphone as in Apple's speech recognition example.

However, I've managed to circumvent this by using `AVCaptureSession` to capture audio as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242011/2155985).