# Start Listening When Key Phrase Is Said

Tags: ios, swift

I have question regarding iOS speech recognition API. Is there a way to start listening, like hey Siri/ok, google/hey Alexa, with the API?

My app is a handsfree app and I need the text of what the user said after he/she says the certain keyword: like "Hey Assistant".

Answer (score 0):

You could listen continuously and then just check for the phrase you're looking for.

This question has some examples of continuous recognition: 
[Continuous speech recogn. with SFSpeechRecognizer (ios10-beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821826/continuous-speech-recogn-with-sfspeechrecognizer-ios10-beta)

Comment: doesn't the api limit to 1 minute audio, or is it not there for continuous recognittion

Comment: You're right it does look like they're limiting it to a minute. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/?time=592